# Test killed with quit: ran too long

Tags: go

I run `go test` and got timout error:

```
*** Test killed with quit: ran too long (10m0s).
FAIL    call/httptest   600.050s
```

How to extend timeout and make it bigger than 10 minutes?

Comment: you can use the `-timeout` argument. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929790/how-to-set-the-go-timeout-flag-on-go-test

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `go test -timeout <duration>`, e.g.:

```
$ go test -timeout 20m
```

The default is 10m.

From [the docs](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#ParseDuration):

> Valid time units are "ns", "us" (or "µs"), "ms", "s", "m", "h".

Answer (score 3):

By default, timeout exit after 10 minutes

`go test --help`

`-timeout d
        If a test binary runs longer than duration d, panic.
        If d is 0, the timeout is disabled.
        The default is 10 minutes (10m).`