# How to check if sync.WaitGroup.Done() is called in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, go, synchronization, waitgroup

Let's say I have a function if that is executed asynchronous as a go routine:

```
func f(wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer wg.Done()
    // Do sth
}

main(){
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go f(&wg)
    wg.Wait() // Wait until f is done
    // ...
}
```

How would I create a unit test for `f` that makes sure `wg.Done()` is called?

One option is to call `wg.Done()` in the test directly after the `f` is called. If `f` fails to call `wg.Done()` the test will panic which is not nice.
Another option would be to create an interface for `sync.WaitGroup` but that seems a bit weird.

Comment: You can use `reflect` to inspect the counter value. This however relies on unexported fields which are not covered by the "backwards compatibility" promise that Go provides. So when you upgrade to another Go version, your tests *could* break. https://play.golang.org/p/uDqvm68h_V2

Comment: In fact, 1.18 does seem to change the structure of the WaitGroup from that of 1.17, so if you do use the suggestion above and then in early 2021 you upgrade to 1.18... them tests are guaranteed to blow up. [1.17](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.17/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L28) and [current master](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ad7db1f90fb66f00f5b020360aabd9f27d1c764f/src/sync/waitgroup.go#L29-L30)

Comment: If Done is not called, then Wait won’t return and the tests will be broken. You don’t need to inspect the internals of the WaitGroup.

Comment: @JimB The test itself doesn't need to be executed as a go routine.

Comment: If the function requires a WaitGroup for coordination, and expects to be run as a goroutine, then run it as a goroutine.

Comment: @JimB why? Note that this is a unit test and not integration test.

Comment: Because that is how you would test this this code. There is nothing wrong with using a goroutine in a unit test that is testing code which is a goroutine. Concurrency is fundamental to the use of the language, not something reserved only for integration.

Comment: @JimB Right, in my code I use it as a go routine but what if others want to use `f` synchronously? Btw, won't the test just stall instead of failing if `Wait` never returns?

Comment: If a function requires a WaitGroup, it would be unusual to not use it as a goroutine, and there really wouldn’t be any reason not to. If you want to fail on a blocked Wait, you use another goroutine and fail after a timeout.

Comment: It just seems like we are bending over backwards for something that could easily be mocked? Adding a timeout to the test means that we are hardware dependent all of a sudden.

Comment: @RasmusN you're the one bending over backwards here - first to avoid goroutines in a test (probably because your experience with concurrency in other languages lends you to think of it as something to be kept out of unit tests), then to argue with JimB instead of learning from their contributions.  Let Go be Go.  Let experienced people like JimB guide you.

Comment: If you are worried about the test running interminably in CI if that `wg.Done()` isn't called, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929790/how-to-set-the-go-timeout-flag-on-go-test might help you

Comment: Unless you’ve solved the halting problem, you cannot prove that any set of tests will complete. Why are you planning for the test to routinely fail? We always defer Done at the start of the function precisely so it can never be skipped, and removing it would be obvious in review. If you were to somehow skip it, the test times out once and you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I create a unit test for f that makes sure wg.Done() is called?

Something like this:

```
func TestF(t *testing.T) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    // run the task asynchronously
    go f(wg)

    // wait for the WaitGroup to be done, or timeout
    select {
    case <-wrapWait(wg):
        // all good
    case <-time.NewTimer(500 * time.Millisecond).C:
        t.Fail()
    }
}

// helper function to allow using WaitGroup in a select
func wrapWait(wg *sync.WaitGroup) <-chan struct{} {
    out := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        out <- struct{}{}
    }()
    return out
}
```

You don't inspect the WaitGroup directly, which you can't do anyway. Instead you assert that the function **behaves as expected**, given the expected input.

In this case, the expected input is the WaitGroup argument and the expected behavior is that `wg.Done()` gets called eventually. What does that mean, in practice? It means that if the function is successful a WaitGroup with count 1 will reach 0 and allow `wg.Wait()` to proceed.

The statement `defer wg.Done()` at the beginning of `f` already makes sure that the test is resilient to errors or crashes. The addition of a timeout is simply to make sure the test will complete within a reasonable time, i.e. that it doesn't stall your test suite for too long. Personally, I prefer using explicit timeouts, either with timers or with contexts, to 1) avoid problems if someone forgets to set timeouts at the CI level, 2) make the time ceiling available to anyone who checks out the repo and runs the test suite, i.e. avoid dependencies on IDE configs or whatnot.

Comment: instead of sending something to the `out` channel you can also just close it