# How to edit default go test timeout in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: go

I'm trying to edit default test timeout through Visual studio code Settings.json

Here are my go.testFlags:

```
"go.testFlags": [
 "-count=1",
 "1",
 "-v",
 "-timeout 30m"
 ],
```

But when I run test through vsc I see that timeout is still default (30 seconds)

Is there any way I could override default go test timeout setting?

I am aware I can pass it as flag like this:

go test -timeout 30m

Comment: I think this article will help you
Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929790/how-to-set-the-go-timeout-flag-on-go-test)!

Comment: Shot in the dark guess: split up `"-timeout 30m"` into two separate args:  `"-timeout" , "30m"`

Comment: This actually solved it! "-timeout" , "30m" and I was missing ',' at the end. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

You can use`"go.testTimeout": "300s"` on settings.json file. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

just change `go.testTimeout` in setting to 10m

[image: isolated]

or just set `"go.testTimeout": "10m"` on `settings.json` file